# wordpress site Address (URL) accidentally changed

Tags: php, wordpress, frameworks, wordpress-theming, themes

I have made the WordPress e-commerce website on woostify theme. I am making this website on my local host on my machine. I am not using any domain. so, I accidentally changed the site address to sneakereboot.com which I have not purchased or bought it. before it is shoestorewp.com. now I have tried everything and watched every tutorial there is every method is related to only with webhosting. how to resolve the changes or revert the changes to the local host. how to do that my website has gone down. I can't be logged to localhost/shoestore/wp-admin

it shows[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HgE8.png) like this

I have tried and go to my webserver wamp i have gone to my table shoestore in the wp_options

i have changed siteurl and home url to my old localhost URL which is http://shoesstorewp.com

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz8Yg.png)

and nothing is changed i want my website to be backed like before it is not logged in. it is not going to the username password page.

it says like this
shoestorewp.com’s server IP address could not be found.

Comment: Go in table wp_options and check SITEURL and HOME

Comment: yes i have checked it i have changed it to.
before it is
siteurl:http://sneakerreboot.com
home:http://sneakerreboot.com
now
siteurl: http://shoestorewp.com
home: http://shoestorewp.com

tell me where iam doing wrong. did i type both the urls right?

Comment: Dude it's really simple to do go to database and in database there is a table called wp_options and you can find home  and siteurl sections edit them to localhost.

for ex : http://localhost/your_folder_name_in_xamp_or_wamp

also please make sure to clear browser cache or hard refresh web cache using ctrl+shift+r because sometimes changes not showing with first time

Comment: Ok thanks I will give it a try. Do I have to give http:/localhost/your folder like this or just local host? @mithunDeshan

Comment: @HamdMahmood no use ```http://localhost/ " Name of the folder that content website files "``` - replace "" with folder name of your website content are in. for example i have a my web files in below path(using wampp)

C:\wamp64\www\abc

and the url needs to be change like 

```http://localhost/abc/```

Comment: mark as useful so everybody can make a benefit out of it.